# How get the database info on a Wordpress site hosted in Azure?

Tags: wordpress, azure

Our company site is hosted in Azure years ago... It's a *Wordpress* site.

Days ago we are getting this error: **Error establishing a database connection**

It's an error with Database, which is hosted in `us-cdbr-azure-east-c.cloudapp.net`

If we use the credentials in `wp-config.php`, we got the error: `The specified database user/password combination is rejected: Access denied for user`

We verified in `Azure Portal > App Service > Settings > Configuration > Connection Strings > Our Conn. String` and it has the same credentials (**Doubled checked**).

How we can find the current user and password of this database?

We can't find a MySQL Admin in Azure to connect to our Database.

Comment: Seems that you should have an instance of Azure Database for MySQL in your Azure resources. Could you compare the connection string from "Home - 
All resources - Azure Database for MySQL server" - "Connection strings" with the one from App Service?
Also, simply click on a "Reset password" button in the "Overview" blade in order to change the password.

Comment: @Sergeythere is no MySQL in the list of `All resources`. We searched it. :'(

Comment: You said "years ago" - could you please check whether this is Classic deployment and not a new (Resource Manager) one?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the search and type 'us-cdbr-azure-east-c' you should be able to find the cloud service.

Comment: Searching in that way appears: `There are no results matching your filter query`

Comment: the best you can do is open a ticket support